# Screen Capture API _ Set a specific Screen

Tags: http-live-streaming, screen-capture, screensharing

I am using screen capture API to share a window on my Django application, but this API doesn't allow to set a specific screen.
I only want to share a window of specific desktop application on my Django project.
How do I set to share a specific screen of an application using screen capture API or do I have to use other method?
[Screen Sharing]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8R7I.png)

I am following this document.
[(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture)]